# DirectX: Object space to screen space

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx-11

This is driving me crazy! Any help would be appreciated.

I have a 3d model that is drawn to the screen. This definitely works, and the model lies within the screen bounds. I want to calculate the screen coordinates on the CPU of a couple of the vertices.

To do this, I multiply these vertices' positions by the model/view/projection matrix in the same way my vertex shader does:

```
XMVECTOR pos = XMVectorSet(input.x, input.y, input.z, 1);
pos = XMVector3Transform(pos, XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_constantBufferData.model));
pos = XMVector3Transform(pos, XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_constantBufferData.view));
pos = XMVector3Transform(pos, XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_constantBufferData.projection));
```

I then divide pos.X and pos.Y by pos.Z.

How do I interpret the result of pos? I was expecting it to have X and Y coordinates lying between 0 and 1, or possibly -1 and 1, but I am getting numbers such as -3. Am I doing something incorrectly?

For the record, this is part of vertex shader:

```
float4 pos = float4(input.pos, 1.0f);
pos = mul(pos, model);
pos = mul(pos, view);
pos = mul(pos, projection);
output.pos = pos;
```

Thank you in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to divide by the `w` component, **not** the `z`:

```
float3 clipPosition = affineClipPosition.xyz / affineClipPosition.w;
```

If you transformation matrices are valid and applied in the correct order, your `xy` components should be in the range `-1` to `1` and the `z` component between `0` and `1`.

---

- [Affine space - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_subspaces)

Comment: Aha. Yes, I had thought that but my w component was nearly zero: dividing by w made my x and y coordinates be of the order of a million! 

I solved the problem. I was forgetting to retranspose the matrices again before calculating the screen coordinate on the CPU (since HLSL wants the matrices transposed). 

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else hits this problem, I was forgetting that I had transposed the matrices before passing them to HLSL, so I needed to retranspose them back again before using them on the CPU:

```
    XMVECTOR pos = XMVectorSet(input.x, input.y, input.z, 1);
    pos = XMVector3Transform(pos, XMMatrixTranspose(XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_constantBufferData.model)));
    pos = XMVector3Transform(pos, XMMatrixTranspose(XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_constantBufferData.view)));
    pos = XMVector3Transform(pos, XMMatrixTranspose(XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_constantBufferData.projection)));
```

I then needed to divide the pos.X/pos.Y/pos.Z coordinates of pos by pos.W, as Lucius suggested above.

Hope this helps someone!